# What kind of matter's energy density scales as the inverse of the scale factor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, space-expansion, scaling

We know that radiation energy density scales as $a^{-4}$ with EoS parameter ($w=\frac{1}{3}$), matter as $a^{-3}$ with ($w=0$), curvature as $a^{-2}$ with ($w=-\frac{1}{3}$).

Then which kind of matter density scales as $a^{-1}$ with $w=-\frac{2}{3}$? As for these kind of matter $w<-\frac{1}{3}$, these would cause accelerated expansion of the universe.

Are these kinds of matter known and studied in cosmology?

Comment: If I was Sam Bankman-Fried, I would hype it as **dark energy 2.0** (anything with $w<-\frac{1}{3}$ could drive the acceleration of the universe, including  dark energy 1.0 with $w=-1$) and solicit investment in this novel clean energy. And even better, SBF would have bundled this **dark energy 2.0** with the **Fusion breakthrough** of Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory, and parked the giddy investors' money in the **wormhole** created by Google's Santa Barbara quantum computer lab.